# "Where" clause or pull data base on id from other file in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on an application where I load 5 articles on a page called stories. When I click an individual story it's supposed to load it's details on the resulting page. Now the stories are coming from a local page (local database) and I use .map to map out all the stores found in the database. This part is fine.

```
export default {
  article: [
    {
      id: 1,
      headline: "Climate Change",
      body:"Loren",
    },
```

So this is essentially my "database".

Now upon clicking a story I have my [stories].js page with the following with the code that lets me get the ID of my story, so If I click the climate change story I get the ID of 1.

```
const SingleStoryPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { storyDetail } = router.query;
```

The problem is, while I get the ID of 1, I do not know how to specify to only load the climate change story as I am still using map. I know this is of course wrong but, is there a way I can filter on map? something like a where clause where ID = 1 ?
The other examples I looked at loaded the data fine because they used an API and selected the data based on the id which is `storyDetail` in my case. But seeing as I am not using an API just pulling from a local file. I am not sure how to accomplish this "where" feature.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method instead. Something like: `articleArray.find(({ id }) => id === storyDetail)`.